# Wald's Identity for non-i.i.d. Case

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walk

I am looking for Wald's  Identity for non-i.i.d. case as discussed in the following links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation

[What are the assumptions for applying Wald's equation with a stopping time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064911/what-are-the-assumptions-for-applying-walds-equation-with-a-stopping-time)

Can someone please refer me to a book where I can find discussion about the Wald's Identity for non-i.i.d. case. Also, from assumptions mentioned on Wikipedia page it is not clear to me that for what level of dependence between random variables the general version of Wald's identity will not hold.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I am having the exact same problem